# Run background task on repeat every N

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and I want a loop to run in the background let's say every 60 seconds. I found a plugin for Django which seems like it got what I need, but i'm not sure how to make it work. I understand you put the @background in, but as far as I understand django. This goes into a view right? But before the code is being  loaded the first time, doesn't the webpage have to be loaded first?

I'm talking about the following plugin

https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear:

- You need to install the app (`pip install ...`, adding to `INSTALLED_APPS`, running `migrate`)
- You need to define a (or some) function which you decorate with `@background`
- You need to call these decorated functions, maybe in a view or somewhere else. This will add the function to a queue (a table in the database, which was created when running `migrate`).
- You need to run `python manage.py process_tasks` as a regular cron job; this will read the queue and execute the functions. As long as you don't call this, no function will be executed and queue will just keep filling.

Does this answer your question? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: That's also how I understood it once I read further, thank you. When I try to run `python manage.py process_tasks` im receiving this error **RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>**

Comment: I have added it inside a view and made a call for the function but nothing ever seemed to happen. I guess the process_tasks is a must, but doesn't work properly for me.

Comment: I'm reading online that other fixed it by noticing that one of their app was missing a _init_ file, but my apps are not missing them.

Comment: @LesnieSncheider We will need more info to help you further. Can you add your decorates function and the full error stackstrace to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to go in a new direction and if this is an asynchronous command that you are running periodically, consider using celery with module celery-beat.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Celery although it's only Linux! Right now while testing my application it's on Windows unfortunately, but im planning on migrating to Linux once finished for the performance.